# Invoking cmd with Groovy and SoapUI not working

Tags: groovy, soapui, putty, scp

I'm working with SoapUI to test a webservice. My client runs Windows 7 and the server runs on Linux. For some testcases I need to change a configuration file on a remote server. I wanted to achieve this with a groovy script. First step is pushing the file with scp (kscp) and as second step restarting the application via ssh (kitty).

The first command does not work. The second just fine. What am I doing wrong?

```
def scp = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:/pathTo/kscp.exe -pw password fileToUpload.txt user@host:/pathTo/remoteLocation/")
scp.waitFor()
def ssh = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:/pathTo/kitty.exe -load profile -m C:/pathTo/scriptToBeRunOnRemote")
ssh.waitFor()
```

If I execute the first command in a normal cmd it just works fine. I also tried to run the same command from a .bat file without success.

Thanks in advance for your help and tips!

**EDIT (SOLUTION FOUND)**

I just found the solution.

```
def scp = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c cd C:/pathTo/ & kscp.exe -pw password fileToUpload.txt user@host:/pathTo/remoteLocation/")
```

Comment: *does not work* - *without success* - Means what? What does it do instead? Error message? Screenshot?

Comment: Most probably a permissions issue

Comment: @MartinPrikryl does no work / without success means that nothing happens. If I "log.info(scp)" the output is a process Id without any errors. But the file has not been transfered.

where could the permission issue happen? Both .exe files are in the same directory where I have full permission (no admin permissions) and the server folder permissions should be ok due to the fact that the command works (and the file is being transferred) when I use the regular windows cmd with the same command

Comment: What output do you get when you run `kscp.exe -pw password fileToUpload.txt user@host:/pathTo/remoteLocation/` from a batch file?

Comment: nothing at all. just a new blank line with a blinking cursor in the cmd window. Could it be an "issue" with kscp? That it's trying to open another process (like kitty itself)? I'm just so confused that it's working in a regular cmd but not from the command within the script which is basically the same thing (new process).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution found**

```
def scp = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c cd C:/pathTo/ & kscp.exe -pw password fileToUpload.txt user@host:/pathTo/remoteLocation/")
```